# How to run a file from URL using Expect?

Tags: bash, shell, wget, expect

In an expect script, I'd like to download a file and execute it. I've tried these options so far:

Attempt 1 - Simply download and execute

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn wget mysite.com/file.sh
spawn /bin/sh file.sh
```

The /bin/sh command executes before the file finishes downloading

Attempt 2 - Pipe content to executable

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn /bin/sh <(curl -s mysite.com/file.sh)
```

I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: <(curl: No such file or directory
send: spawn id exp6 not open
while executing
```

I tried escaping characters a few different ways

Attempt 3 - Use eval

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn eval "\$(/bin/sh <\(curl -s mysite.com/file.sh\))"
```

This gives this error:

```
couldn't execute "eval": no such file or directory
while executing
```

I tried with and without escaping characters

Comment: why use `expect` instead of regular bash?

Comment: Well, the actual script has a several prompts that I'm automating. I just didn't see a need to show that part. It all works if I already have the script downloaded. I just want the expect script to do the downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system <args>` passes the arguments to `sh`. Therefore you can use the `&&` operator to execute the script after it is executed.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

system wget mysite.com/file.sh && ./file.sh
```

Or if you don't want to save the script at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

system curl mysite.com/file.sh | /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `system` is basically the command I've been looking for. I knew there had to be something besides `spawn`